# Total temperature when combining two systems of unequal temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, equilibrium

I know that intensive properties a characterised by the fact that when you combine two systems (A and B) that have the same value of an intensive property (for example same Temperature) the combined system (AB) will have the same temperature.
$$
T_{AB}=T_A=T_B
$$
but what if $T_A\neq T_B$? Of course from intuition one know that $T_{AB}$ will be somewhere between $T_A$ and $T_B$ based on how large $A$ and $B$ are. But how can one derive the exact formula for $T_{AB}$ in equilibrium with respect to $T_A$ and $T_B$ and lets say $N_A$ and $N_B$ which are the number of particles in system $A$ and $B$, representing their size.
PS: This might be derivable in multiple ways. But I would like to derive it in the frame of thermodynamics with Maxwell and Gibbs equations and stuff like that

Comment: You will need more information about the systems, such as the heat capacities of the materials they are comprised of, etc.

Comment: The equilibrium state is obtained by maximizing the entropy, with the typical result that the final temperatures are equal. Then, this final temperature can be found from conservation of energy as applied to the [sensible heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensible_heat), mediated by the heat capacities. Please clarify if this is what you’re asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Total temperature when combining two systems of unequal temperature

Just want to point out that the title of your post could imply that temperature is an extensive property, i.e., that you can add two temperatures to obtain a "total" temperature.

> But how can one derive the exact formula for $T_{AB}$ in equilibrium

As @Matt Hanson pointed out, you will need more information about the systems, such as the heat capacities of the materials they are comprised.

But let's say as a simple example you are mixing two identical ideal gases of different temperature together in a rigid adiabatic chamber (i.e., the ideal gases are an isolated system). For an isolated system you have.

$$\Delta U_{A}+\Delta U_{B}=0$$

Then since for an ideal gas, the internal energy is a function of temperature only, you have, where the final temperatures of both A and B are the same, say $T_{f}$,

$$n_{A}C_{VA}(T_{f}-T_{A})+ n_{B}C_{VB}(T_{f}-T_{B})=0$$

Where $n$ is the number of moles and $C_V$ is the molar heat capacity of each gas at constant volume.

Hope this helps.